# Trouble with installing Bookworm on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: software-installation, dependencies

When I try to install the Bookworm using the terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install bookworm
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 bookworm : Depends: com.github.babluboy.bookworm but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the elementary PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
apt-get install com.github.babluboy.bookworm
```

And once bookworm is installed, remove the elementary PPA.